# Enable feature works in powershell console but not as script

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have a script that is supposed to install features based on a list provided. The out is fine, but the commands always fail to install but they work in the powershell console.

```
$features_to_enable=New-Object 
System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]

# We only want to read the features that are enabled. 
Get-Content 'C:\features.txt' | Where-Object {$_ -match ".*Enabled"} | 
ForEach-Object {
  $features_to_enable.Add($_)
}

# Converted List to Array
$features_to_enable.ToArray()

forEach($feature in $features_to_enable) {
  #Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "$($feature)" -All -NoRestart
  dism /Online /Enable /FeatureName:"$($feature)" /All
}
```

Using the enable windows optional feature method I get this error:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : Feature name NetFx4ServerFeatures                                                           
Enabled is unknown.
At C:\features.ps1:12 char:3
+   Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "$($feature)" -A ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand
```

Using dism within the powershell script leads:

```
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.16299.15

Image Version: 10.0.16299.125


Error: 87

The enable option is unknown. 
For more information, refer to the help by running DISM.exe /?.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that the string $feature actually is "Enabled" and I wasn't able to see that they were on the same line.

In the end, I solved the problem by doing this:

```
$f = $feature.replace(' ' , '').replace('Enabled', '')
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $f -All -NoRestart
```

Answer (score 0):

From the `dism` version, I think Windows 10 is running on your computer, so PowerShell is recommended.

```
$features = (Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | ? state -eq 'enabled').FeatureName
foreach($feature in $features) {
     Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName $feature -Online -All -NoRestart
    }
```

This works for me after testing. :)